# How do I copy element which reference from int array >=40 to a new String array

Tags: java

I  have `int` array and `String` array of the same length, and  want to create a new `String` array containing elements from the original `String` array; but only those elements that are at positions where the `int` on the corresponding position in the `int` array is *less* or equal to 40.

```
public void check (int[]a,string []y){
 string[]copy =new string[]
for(int I=0,I=j,k;k<copy.length,I<a.length; I++,j++,k++){
 if(a[I]>=50)
         y[j]=copy[k]
```

}

Comment: Java naming conventions would tell you a variable name should start with a lower case. Only a type name should start with an upper case

Comment: And javac would tell you this code does not compile

Comment: Do you mean creating a new `String` array which would only contain values from the original `int` array that are >= 40? You can use `Integer.toString()` for the conversion,  but first you should make the code compilable.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I mean   Cinnam

Comment: Then I'd suggest using a list like `ArrayList<String>` and add the required elements to it in a simple for loop. You can get the array in the end using `yourList.toArray()` if you want.

Comment: into[]a={90,60,40,10}
string []={"A","b","c","d"}  


My new array supposed  to contain values >=40
my new Array ={"c","d"}

Comment: I am forced to use ond-D array

Comment: I see. So you have `int` array and `String` array of the same length, and you want to create a new `String` array containing elements from the original `String` array; but only those elements that are at positions where the `int` on the corresponding position in the `int` array is *less* or equal to 40. If that's correct, please edit this clarification into your original question.

Comment: Oh yeah Cinnamon ^_^

Comment: Ok, now try to solve it. If you only want to use arrays, you will first have to count the number of values in the `int` array, which are <= 40. That will be a simple `for` loop and a counter. Then you will know how big the new array will have to be, so you can create it. Then in another loop you will copy the strings to the new array. That can be simply `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {...`. Use `i` as an index to the `int` and old `String` arrays. For the new array you will need a separate index, which you will increment only after each copied element.

Comment: Now  I define the `size` of the new Array and used one variable for `int` and  Old  `String ` array

How do I copy process
`public void check(int[]input,String[]a,String[]copy){﻿         int counter = 0;﻿       for(in t x =0 ;x<input.length;x++)﻿            if(  [x]<=40){﻿               counter++;﻿              copy=new String[counter];﻿            }﻿       for (int i = 0,j=0; i < a.length;i++,j++){﻿            if(input[i]<=40){﻿                a[i]=copy[j];﻿            } `

Answer (score -2):

You will need to specify the length of the array.

i.e

```
string[] copy = new string[20]; <---- like this
```

it also helps to use   ;  <---- at the end of each command. Like a period in a sentence...

I think this is might be what you really wanted:

public class intToStrng {

```
public static void main(String[]  args)
{

    int[] ints = {2, 3, 4,5,  6, 7,};

    String[] stng = new String[ints.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<ints.length; i ++)
    {
        stng[i] = Integer.toString(ints[i]);
    }



}
```

}

Comment: string is not a Java type